# How can i send data from one module to another?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

i want to send data from one of my modules to another module, which handles the data.

I got three modules: Requester, Controller, Displayer

**Controller:** Inits Requester and Displayer

**Requester:** Makes a server request and gets response data stored in an variable *responseData*

Now i want to send this variable to the **Controller** and from there it should be passed to the **Displayer**

I don't know how i should implement this, because I'm new to JavaScript and those Design Patterns.

For this context I'm using the Revealing Module Pattern...

```
App.Displayer = (function() {...})();
App.Controller = (function() {...})();
App.Requester = (function() {...})();
```

Comment: You might want to look into an MVC framework like AngularJS, it'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

The revealing module pattern is used to keep functions private inside of each module. Functions inside the 
`(function(){//here})()` pattern cannot be accessed outside of module. To answer your question, when you want to reveal the data, you simply return the object `(function(){return{key: value}})()`and you can access it like module.key = value. To pass this public object, you can pass it in as an argument to the module.